# problemas com HTML e PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Estou aprendendo as artes ninjas do PHP e meu código vem dando uma pequena dor de cabeça.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <section class="painel novidades">  
        <h2>Novidades</h2>
        <ol>

<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos");

while($produtos = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo "<li>;
            <a href=\"produto.php?\" id=<?php echo $id ?>>;
                <figure>;
                    <img class=\"foto\" src=\"img/produtos/miniatura2.png\">;
                        "<figcaption>.$exibe[nome].$exibe[valor].</figcaption>";
               </figure>;
            </a>;
         </li>";
}
?>
```

A intenção é que sejam mostrados os produtos vindo direto do banco de dados, obviamente será o mesmo produto, mas o que está errado ai? (A conexão com o banco de dados já foi feita mais acima no código).

Comment: Qual é o erro que está dando?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in /home/thiago/novosite/index.php on line 45, quando não é esse erro aparece um no lugar de cada imagem dizendo que não foram encontradas as variáveis se não me engano, "se não me engano"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria da seguinte forma

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <section class="painel novidades">  
            <h2>Novidades</h2>
            <ol>

   <?php
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos");

   while($produtos = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   ?>
        <li>
            <a href=\"produto.php?\" id=<?php echo $id ?>
                 <figure>
                     <img class=\"foto\" src=\"img/produtos/miniatura2.png\">
                         <figcaption><? echo $exibe[nome].$exibe[valor]; ?></figcaption>
                 </figure>
             </a>
        </li>
  <?
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: Funcionou também, Obrigado!

Comment: Ok, só dê um aceite na minha resposta! Valeu!

Comment: Sim! Sou novato aqui e.e, foi mal.

Answer (score 1):

Faça assim, seu código vai funcionar:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <section class="painel novidades">  
        <h2>Novidades</h2>
        <ol>

<?php
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos");

    while($produtos = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="produto.php" id="'.$id.'">';
        echo '<figure>';
        echo '<img class="foto" src="img/produtos/miniatura2.png">';
        echo '<figcaption>'.$produtos[nome].$produtos[valor].'</figcaption>';
        echo '</figure>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
}
?>
```

Veja onde `$id` está puxando. Se você quer puxar a ID do produto então você deve fazer `$produtos[id]`

Comment: Obrigado cara funcionou perfeitamente ;)